# Trouble installing ncurses

Tags: apt, compiling, 19.04, git, ncurses

I've git cloned a program I need: https://github.com/dbdexter-dev/meteor_demod

When I try to compile it with `make`, I get a `fatal error: ncurses.h: No such file or catalog`

So I tried `sudo apt install ncurses`, but then I get `Couldn't find package ncurses`.

So i `git clone https://github.com/millionbonus/ncurses.git`, but when I `make`, it says `no makefile found`.

I've run out of ideas. Any help, please? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this website https://www.osetc.com/en/how-to-install-ncurse-library-in-ubuntu-debian-centos-fedora-linux.html with the following comment, which worked:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
```